# How to redirect to action from JavaScript method?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have an input type="button"

```
<input type="button" name="DeleteJob" runat="server" value="Löschen" onclick="DeleteJob()" />
```

and JavaScript method:

```
function DeleteJob() {

    if (confirm("Do you really want to delete selected job/s?"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

How can I instead return true, redirect to Action DeleteJob?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteJob(string selectedObject)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Is your DeleteJob method a HttpGet function ?

Comment: Http Get is meant to be idempotent.  You should be using a Post or a Delete instead.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To redirect:

```
function DeleteJob() {
    if (confirm("Do you really want to delete selected job/s?"))
        window.location.href = "your/url";
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: try this in IE? I have a problem with window.location.href

Comment: which version? In IE6 it doesn't work, but IE6 is not a browser anymore.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that i didn't use this in ie because i need to know url referrer.

Comment: Although IE6 is not a browser anymore, its a pity many large companies still use it and require it to work with in house applications.

Comment: @PeterPorfy In addition to your answer, what would you do to **send some get/post parameter** to it as well

Comment: @sumitramteke you cannot create a post request like this (this is actually rewriting the browser location which will result in a get request) but you can easily add get parameters: window.location.href = "your/url?key=value";

Answer (score 36):

```
function DeleteJob() {
    if (confirm("Do you really want to delete selected job/s?"))
        window.location.href = "/{controller}/{action}/{params}";
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: This works only if your web application is in the root of the site, though.

Comment: Thumbs up for the asp routing-way

Answer (score 17):

I wish that I could just comment on yojimbo87's answer to post this, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.  It was pointed out that this relative path only works from the root:

```
        window.location.href = "/{controller}/{action}/{params}";
```

Just wanted to confirm that you can use @Url.Content to provide the absolute path:

```
function DeleteJob() {
    if (confirm("Do you really want to delete selected job/s?"))
        window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/{controller}/{action}/{params}")';
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: This only works if the Javascript function is embedded in the View itself, right? It won't work if your Javascript is located in a separate file.

Comment: You can put link to your action inside a View inside <script> tags use global variable var LoadNewDocURL = '@Url.Action("Edit", "SaleDocuments")'; Then add your params to this variable.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe better to make an anchor with DeleteJob url instead of button?

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("DeleteJob", "YourController", new {selectedObject="someObject"})%>" onclick="return DeleteJob()">Löschen</a>
```

and use your javascript you wrote already:

```
function DeleteJob() {

        if (confirm("Do you really want to delete selected job/s?"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

So if function return true - you will be redirected. If function return false - you still stay on the page.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `@Url.Action method`. This will work and determines the correct route regardless of what IIS server you deploy to.

Example-

```
window.location.href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")";
```

so in the case of the **Index action** on the **Home controller** -

```
window.location.href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
```

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this a little because I wanted to use Knockout to bind the button to the click event. Here's my button and the relevant function from inside my view model.

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary showBusy" data-bind="click: back">Back to Dashboard</a>

var vm = function () {
...
    self.back = function() {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("LicenseDashboard", "Application")';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*(This is more of a comment but I can't comment because of the low reputation, somebody might find these useful)*

If you're in **sth.com/product** and you want to redirect to **sth.com/product/index** use

```
window.location.href = "index";
```

If you want to redirect to **sth.com/home**

```
window.location.href = "/home";
```

and if you want you want to redirect to **sth.com/home/index**

```
window.location.href = "/home/index";
```

Answer (score 1):

Youcan either send a Ajax request to server or use window.location to that url.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way.  It isn't really that useful but showing for completeness:

Handle all your logic in your imported javascript file

```
function someFunction(){
  var x = $('#whoknows').val();
  var y = something;
  values = {
   property1 = x;
   property2 = y;
  };
  save(values);  <--- call the method in the view here
}
```

Then ONLY do the actual call to the controller from your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function save(values) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { _values_ = 1 })'
            .replace('_values_=1', new URLSearchParams(values));
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```