# javascript redirect to controller action asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm developing an **ASP.Net MVC 5** project . I need to redirect page when I submit something. I used this Javascript code :

```
return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Edited...');window.location.href = 'ShowColor';</script>");
```

when I edit something in

http://localhost:56583/Admin/EditColor/27

I want redirect my page to

http://localhost:56583/Admin/ShowColor

With above code it goes to

http://localhost:56583/Admin/EditColor/ShowColor

Also I used below code according to [Redirecting to action from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808536/redirecting-to-action-from-javascript) but it didn't work too :

```
return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Edited...');window.location.href = '@Url.Action('ShowColor', 'Admin')';</script>");
```

I have no idea how fix it. thanks for any help

Comment: Why not just `return RedirectToAction("ShowColor", "Admin");`?

Comment: Because I want to show an alert too @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to relative paths. Something like the below should make it relative to the domain.

```
window.location.href='/Admin/ShowColor'
```

Answer (score 0):

To show an alert and redirect, you need to make an anchor tag that invokes your controller action, then the controller would look something like:

```
    public ActionResult AlertAndRedirect()
    {
        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Good work, click to redirect.');</script>");
    }
```

Which will pop a dialog box, then redirect you.