# javascript location.href redirect from one view to another

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, redirect, model-view-controller

how can we redirect from one view to another using `window.location.href` with parameters?

> code in javascript

```
window.location.href = "your/url?10&12";
```

and my method

```
public ActionResult url(int val1, int val2)
{

}
```

> both val1 and val2 is 0

what can we do here to get the value?

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: javascript and asp.net mvc

Comment: What are you doing with that url vals exactly? The easiest way to send those vals would be ajax post (get them from url and send via ajax).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808536/redirecting-to-action-from-javascript

Comment: @dente R. How can I redirect to action method which contains parameters

Comment: It needs to be `"your/url?val1=10&val2=12"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use url helpers when generating urls to a controller action.

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Url", "Home")' + '?val1=' +x+'&val2='+y;
```

and add [HttpGet] decorator on Action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult url(int val1, int val2)
{

}
```